# State of the art for Object detection/image recognition

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, tensorflow, image-classification

I was asked to verify the feasibility for solving a particular problem: recognizing for a fashion brand the model of its products.

I have little experience with image recognition in general, I always used Google Vision Api or some pre trained nets from Google/tensorflow like the VGG-16.

I am wondering: **Do you think this level of granularity can be achieved?**

I guess I should for example train the last layer of a pre-trained network, but I need many images to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe.

Do they have a unique feature on the item  (e.g. a polo player, a red sole) the model can be trained on? I have seen people try identifying clothing model from images via Google's Vision API and it didn't work well. If you are in a fashion category where the business model is to copy designs like H&M or Zara do, you're likely going to have trouble.